# change or possibly remove the tab border on tabwidget

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

i recently customized the UI of my tabs by setting a backgroundResource on each tab, then switch between selected / unselected depending on which tab is currently in focus. I got one problem though, there seems to be a white border that comes with the tabwidget by default that stretches over to the other (unselected) tabs at the bottom. I wanna change the color or possibly remove it. Is there anyway of doing that ?

//thx in advance for replies

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245382/how-to-get-rid-of-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-tabhost

Comment: tried to nest it in a linearLayout as the answer on that link but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: i found that the solution on that link only pushes the bar to the bottom of the activity.

Comment: Try also to set this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#attr_android:tabStripEnabled. But I think this is available from API 8.

Comment: When tab bar is at the bottom of the screen, you can try to set android:layout_marginBottom of TabWidget to negative values.

Comment: thx i'll try that, yeah i noticed that they added some new layout attributes to the 2.2 api , unfortunetly i'm developing for 2.1 but i'll try the suggested solutions, thx for the replies :)

Comment: yeah it worked thank you! :D , i put a negative margin and had to put a padding on top of the main view xml and all the other views that are under the tabs to show the content correctly, thx once again :)