# Get rid of the line under TabWidget

Tags: android, line, tabwidget

I've got simple tab activity with next layout:

```
    <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
    android:background="#ffffff00"        />

<FrameLayout            
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
   android:background="#ffffff00"          />
```

I use buttons as indicators for tabs

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1")
                .setIndicator(new Button(this))                
                .setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity1.class)));   

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2")
                .setIndicator(new Button(this))                
                .setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity2.class)));
```

In this case FrameLayout always got black line and shadow effect on top (you can see it under buttons):

[image]

**The question is: How can I get rid of this line? Where is the method that draws it in Android sources?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apply a custom theme to your activity, and null out the android:windowContentOverlay attribute.

Define a theme in themes.xml:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="if you want">
  ...   
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  ...
</style>
```

Apply the theme on your application or the activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@style/YourTheme"
  ... >
```

Hope it helps. It caused me lots of headache...

Comment: This also removes the window content overlay for the current activity though. Is there no way to remove only the overlay for the tab host's intents?

Comment: THANK YOU! And for all who have a theme already on the application tag like hiding the title bar for example, look here for inheriting from a parent style: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles

Comment: @SpK : you commented on my problem yesterday. That problem looks same to this problem, but even this approach din't work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

In your layout xml:

```
<TabWidget ... 
    android:tabStripEnabled="false" >

 ... 

</TabWidget>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Actually shadow on FrameLayout and not on TabWidget.

Comment: android:tabStripEnabled is available only available from 2.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way of doing that is to nest the tabwidget in a LinerLayout...
Look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245382/how-to-get-rid-of-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-tabhost)

Comment: This is not my case. He talks about line on TabWidget, but I talk about line on RelativeLayout. Even if I put TabWidget to bottom then RelativeLayout will always have this line and shadow.

Comment: You're speaking about the black line just below the tabs?

Comment: Yes. Even if I put something between FrameLayout and TabWidget this line will be on the FrameLayout.

Comment: I think this have somethin to do with Android styles maybe like a shadow or something they are adding, but I don't know where to look

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't get rid of it.  This is a result of how the `TabWidget` is implemented.  Internally the `TabWidget` is an `ActivityGroup` and the contents of each tab is its own `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is to use the library provided by GrreenDroid: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=274

Just have a look at The GDTabActivity, you will be able to tweak everything and get rid of this Bar.

http://android.cyrilmottier.com/medias/actionbar/action_bar_4.png