# Remove bottom line from tab bar

Tags: android, tabbar

I want to remove default line that appears on bottom of tab bar. I tried followings :

```
android:tabStripEnabled="false"  
tabHost.getTabWidget.setStripEnabled(false);
```

Also tried wrapping in LinearLayout as suggested on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245382/how-to-get-rid-of-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-tabhost)

How to remove that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used custom view to remove lines from tab bar.

**Custom layout for tab view :**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tab_desc"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Set tab view :**

```
private void setUpTabs() {
    TabSpec spec0 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab");
    spec0.setContent(R.id.tab_list);
    spec0.setIndicator(tabView(R.drawable.image));
    tabHost.addTab(spec0);
}


// Return view for tab
private View tabView(int drawableId) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_image,
                                tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
    imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed it using

```
 // Create Child Tab1
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("child1").setIndicator("your text",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image)),
            yourclass.class, null);

 mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your background color));
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

I set the background color and then set the image on the tab using the code above the blue line automatically gone, hope this help to you.

Comment: I already have a background image for tabWidget. Setting background color will overlap the image.

Comment: have you tried setting this?? When you set background color it hides that blue line.

Comment: Yes I did. But that hides image, too.

Comment: Tried it. Still have that line at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

use this code and remove line from tabhost bottom

```
android:tabStripEnabled="true"  
tabHost.getTabWidget.setStripEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this attribute in TabLayout

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Full Example :

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_27sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/challengeType"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
   >
```